# Running createIPA task following Xcode 10 upgrade

Tags: ios, gradle, libgdx, robovm

Following installation of latest Xcode, running gradle task createIPA to create my iOS package with robovm produces error

> No SDK found matching version string 11.4

Answer (score 0):

Following the Xcode upgrade I just:

- Started Xcode
- Updated 12.0 in robovm.xml in my ios module

Ran createIPA gradle task again. Problem solved.